# C programming return 0 does not terminate the program

Tags: c, exit, terminate

I wrote this shell for my operating systems course, and for some reason my main function doesn't terminate when I type "exit", its supposed to break from the while loop and then return 0 to main, which should end the program, but instead it just keeps going.

In fact, it will tell me its "a bout to exit" and then it will go back into the while loop where it keeps running as usual.

Anybody see the problem? Thank you for all your help

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LENGTH 1000
#define MAXCMD 11
void init(char *temp);
void clean(char **orderedIds);

int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{ 
    char temp[LENGTH];
    char * tok;
    char c = '\0';
    int *ret_status; 
    pid_t pid; 
    printf("\n$");
    int i, j = 0;   
    while(c !=EOF) 
    { 
        //while not ^D // Source: LinuxGazzette Ramankutty
        c = getchar();    
        if(c=='\n')
        { //enter command
            char **orderedIds = malloc(MAXCMD * sizeof(char*)); 
            for (i=0; i<MAXCMD; i++)
            {
                orderedIds[i] = malloc(MAXCMD * sizeof(char*)); 
            }
            int k=0; 
            tok = strtok(temp, " "); 
            while (tok !=NULL)
            { 
                strcpy(orderedIds[k], tok);
                k++;
                tok = strtok (NULL, " ");
            } 
            orderedIds[k] = NULL; //END with NULL 
            init(temp); //initialize the array 
            pid = fork(); 
            if (pid != 0)
            {
                //printf("Waiting for child (%d)\n", pid);
                pid = wait(ret_status);
            } 
            else 
            {
                if (strcmp(orderedIds[0],"exit")==0)
                { //check for exit
                    printf("Thank you, now exiting\n");
                    break;
                } 
                if (execvp(orderedIds[0], orderedIds))
                {
                    printf("%s\n", orderedIds[0]);
                    puts(strerror(errno));
                    exit(127);
                }
            }
            clean(orderedIds);
            printf("%s", &c);
            printf("$ ");
        } 
        else 
        {
            strncat(temp, &c, 1);                                      
        }
    }                                                                          
    printf("\n I'm a bout to exit!");                                          
    return 0;                                                                  
    exit(0);                                                                   
}                                                                                  

void init(char *temp)
{
    //Function to initialize/rest=et the array                   
    int i;                                                                     
    for(i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)
    {                                                   
        temp[i] = 0;                                                       
    }                                                                          
}

void clean(char **orderedIds)
{
    //garbage collection                                 
    int i;                                                                     
    for(i=0; i<MAXCMD; i++)
    {                                                   
        free(orderedIds[i]);                                               
    }                                                                          
    free(orderedIds);                                                          
}
```

Comment: Very interesting style of indentation. I'm not sure either i should reindent it to my style or learn yours. :)

Comment: This is a popular style, used to save lines by having the open { on the end on the previous line rather than a line by itself.

Comment: It's called [*Egyptian Style*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html).

Comment: @Lee Taylor much better(indent)

Comment: Do you understand what `fork` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do a fork(), and it's in the child process where you are checking for the command "exit".  The child process does indeed exit, but the parent process keeps running.  What you should do is check for internal commands (like "exit") *before* you call fork().

Comment: this fixed my looping issue, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, it does exit.  The problem is you are forking execution.  You need to be careful what you do.  I presume that if a child process exits, it is supposed to exit all parent processes up the chain.  You do this:

```
pid = wait(ret_status);
```

But never do anything with the result.  By the way, just because `wait` expects a pointer doesn't mean you should pass it an uninitialised pointer.  You define:

```
int *ret_status;
```

What you really should do is this:

```
int ret_status;
pid = wait(&ret_status);
```

And then test the value of `ret_status`.  If it indicates that you (the parent process) should exit, then you must `break`.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try kill the subprocess when  it finish its work

```
 kill(pid);
```